# @Transactional in spring boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, transactions, spring-data-jpa

This link: https://www.quora.com/When-should-Spring-Boot-methods-use-the-Transactional-annotation

Explain clearly what's **@Transactional** doing, but I still don't understand when should Spring Boot methods use this annotation:

For example:

I have this method:

```
void addPerson () {// code that calls the DAO layer}
```

My method will work well without the **@Transactional** annotation then why i should add this annotation.

More precisely (in spring boot) what's the difference between:

```
@Transactional void addPerson () {// code that calls the DAO layer}
```

and

```
void addPerson () {// code that calls the DAO layer}
```

Or does Spring boot add automatically this annotation so we don't need to add it to our services

Answer (score 12):

You use `@Transcational` when concurrent calls on your API can affect each other.

Let's say you want to add a **Person** (you retreive data from somewhere, create a new **Person** from data and add it to a list of persons). Let's assume in order to create a Person you need a `partner` attribute which is another Person.

Before creating a Person you would search the partner by Id somehwere and add it to the new Person `partner` attribute. But what if during all this Queries the `partner`you wanted to add is deleted somewhere (let's say in the database due to some other query). You'll end up not having the object you requested.

If you use `@Transactional` Spring makes sure all the required data is safe until the **Transaction** ends. Once it ends, the delete request from the `partner` would take place and then you'll have some logic to remove it from the new **Person** object. But that would take place afterwards.

You use `@Transactional` to ensure safety on your "Transactions".

Comment: Thank you for your response, it's explain more what's the use of the annotation @Transactional, but my question is not "why use it"
                                 my question is IN SPRING BOOT "when we should add it"
                                 because i thinks that spring boot make transactions safe by 
                                    adding this annotation automatically somewhere

Comment: I think in newer springboot version 3.0.4 upwards it is by default true except you explicitely set it to false.

Answer (score -1):

By default **SpringBoot** sets the `spring.jpa.open-in-view` property to `true` value, that means Spring automatically makes a transaction for each request.

If you set this property to `false`, you must annotate with `@Transactional` the point where you want to initialize it [Controller|Service|DAO].